# Help my daughter find a childhood song from Sunday school

Tags: resource-request, music, children

My daughter has only six months at best left on the Earth.  A very happy time of her childhood was spent with the Salvation Army as a child.  A part of her life we didn’t share.

She is consumed by a song that she sung at a talent quest at Sunday school and would love to hear it again.  She’s in her 20’s so I imagine it would be an 80’s or 90’s song.  I’ve googled the lyrics and searched everywhere to no avail. Who sung it and where could I find a copy? This is as far as she can remember:

> Dear god why is your book full of thous and thees
> Do you hear my prayer when I bend my knees
> Do you live in a steeple or with some other people
> These are things that I’ve been wondering
>
> Do you have to squeeze to get in my heart
> If you ever sneezed would I fall apart
> Is heaven full of money or just some milk and honey
> These are things that I’ve been wondering
>
> Can you answer all my questions
> Even if I’m not grown up
> Can you give me some suggestions
> How to get as smart as you are.
>
> Dear god.  Sometimes I just wonder about stuff like this

Comment: Jane, just in case I am unable to pursue this quest, here are a couple of links that might be helpful: https://hymnary.org/search?page=0&qu=hymnalNumber%3A1HFS1893%20in%3Ainstances&sort=firstLine  Gives the title of the song, also the first line and the refrain line (where known)

https://hymnary.org/search?qu=all%3Achildrens%20hymns%20in%3Atext    8,484 children’s hymns Gives first line, topic and refrain line (where known)

Comment: My heart goes with you and your dear daughter. Your style of writing makes me think that you wrote the poem by yourself and forgot about it. And some verses like " is heaven full of money or just some milk and honey.." do not appear to have been taken from a time-tested song of small children . What I am trying to say is that the song was perhaps tailored for an occasion. Who  could have better authored it,  than you the parent ?

Comment: I still remember the full text of an elocution which fetched me first prize in 1975; but when I mention it to my aunt,a retired school teacher who had  written the speech for me, she does not remember a word of it ! That is why I suggest that you authored that beautiful poem.

Comment: Dear Jane, I contacted the Salvation Army here in the Scottish Borders, but they have been unable to find any reference to this children's song.  The Captain said she would be happy to meet with you, but I suspect we may live on different continents?  Might I suggest you try to contact a local Salvation Army and they may be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

I remember this song too! It’s from a cassette tape called **”Dear God, were you a kid like me?”**

[image: Dear God, Were You a Kids Like Me? Song About Jesus and Kids]

[Dear God, Were You a Kids Like Me? Song About Jesus and Kids](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004RX1JI8)